# InvalidArgument exception with symfony2

Tags: symfony

When I do `app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-warmup` in the console i'm getting the next error:

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]  
  The service definition "security.access.decision_manager" does not exist.
```

I'm using Symfony2 v2.2.8

I don't use the `security.access.decision_manager` in my own bundles..

I've searched for `security.access.decision_manager` in my project but could not find anything from my bundles...

I there also a way to get a backtrace in the console?

The strange thing is, if I do `app/console cache:clear --env=dev --no-warmup -v` It works fine! And if I do `app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-warmup -v` I get that error again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging hours I've fount the problem!

I was missing the security include in the config_prod.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }
    - { resource: parameters_prod.yml }
    - { resource: security_prod.yml } <-- The missing one
```

Answer (score 0):

try next:

```
rm -rf app/cache/prod/*
rm -rf app/cache/dev/*
```

Comment: @MitchelVerschoof about stacktrace - you can add -v to your command. found at http://blog.nocontext.net/2013/01/get-stack-trace-on-symfony2-command.html

Comment: Hmm get nothing more with -v `app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-warmup -v


                                                                              
  [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]  
  The service definition "security.access.decision_manager" does not exist.   
                                                                              

`

Comment: I did but didn't help